# dimension of a fiber

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In algebraic geometry what is meant by dimension of a fiber

Is it something similar to dimension of solution space in linear algebra

can any one give a good reference on this

Comment: You might need to provide a bit more context.

Comment: Yes sure i will provide